# dotnetopenauth pending request lost

Tags: .net, dotnetopenauth

I have dotnetopenauth working fine as a provider except when a user clicks the submit button multible times. Then the following error occurs:

Throw New InvalidOperationException("There's no pending authentication request!")

What is the best way to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're using `ProviderEndpoint.PendingAuthenticationRequest` to store the request, which is automatically cleared after the response is sent.  So it makes sense that an accidental double-click would result in this error.  To prevent this from happening you'd have to decide how long to store a response in the user's Session and store it yourself, perhaps just before sending the first response.  Then using that instead of `ProviderEndpoint.PendingAuthenticationRequest`.